# Redirect issue in middleware for admin login in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

When login to admin,then page is redirect But 
'**The page isn't redirecting properly**' message show. Please help me

> Middleware  - IsAdmin.php

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

         if (Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
        {
            return redirect ('/administrator');
        }

               return $next($request);
    }
```

> web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'administrator','as' => 'admin.','middleware' => ['auth'],'middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function(){

    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');

    Route::resource('user','AdminController');

    Route::resource('card','AdminCardController');

});
```

Thanx in advanced..

Comment: First merge the two middlewares `'middleware' => ['auth'],'middleware' => 'isAdmin'` ==> `'middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']` and test !!

Comment: After this, getting same issue occur 'The page isn't redirecting properly'

Comment: Ok i think you should place your new middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` instead of `$middleware` in the `App\Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: yes, add in 'protected $routeMiddleware' in kernel.php

Comment: Yes and remove it from `$middleware` and test !!

Comment: This made how can call the class in middelware  but after remove in middelware getting error like 'Class isAdmin does not exist'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155577/discussion-between-maraboc-and-karnail-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you register your middlware in the karnel and try the following code:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
 Route::middleware(['auth', 'IsAdmin'])->group(function () {
   // Your routes 
 });
});
```