# The page isn’t redirecting properly Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

> kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'adminauth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuth::class,
    ];
```

> web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'adminauth'], function() {

        //route for admin dashboard
        Route::get('/admin', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@dashboard',
                'as' => 'dashboard'
        ]);

        //route for admin setting
        Route::get('/admin/setting', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@setting'
        ]);
});
```

> AdminAuth.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        return redirect('/admin/setting');
        //return $next($request);
    }
```

> AdminController.php

```
public function setting() {
      $admin = $this->admin;
      $notification = $this->notification;

      return view('admin/setting')->with(compact(
        'admin',
        'notification'
      ));
    }
```

I'm facing this problem i.e., ***The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.***

I read these posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485574/redirect-issue-in-middleware-for-admin-login-in-laravel), [link2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/the-page-isnt-redirecting-properly), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374520/laravel5-oldmiddleware-the-page-isnt-redirecting-properly?lq=1) but nothing solves my problem.

Comment: `/admin/setting'` uses the `adminauth` middleware but is also where the adminauth middleware will redirect to. That's an infinite redirect

Comment: @apokryfos  Thanx, it solves my problem.

Comment: @apokryfos please post this as a solution so the poster can mark it as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `admin/setting` route uses the `adminauth` middleware, however your `adminauth` middleware will redirect to `admin/setting` if it does not pass.

Just an informative note:

A redirect response is a response with codes between 300-399 and these responses are sent to the browser telling the browser what to do next. Browsers will by default follow redirects and create a new request to the said location.

In your case the browser creates a request to `admin/setting` the middleware fails and tells the browser to redirect to `admin/setting` which will do the exact same thing again. Browsers like Firefox have a built-in mechanism to detect this and instead of flooding your server with requests will just stop this loop and let the user know there's a problem.

To solve this you either need to redirect somewhere else or exclude the `/admin/setting` from the `adminauth` middleware.

The solution will depend on your application.

---

A bit more detail as to *why* Firefox correctly opts to stop the redirects:

According to [section 9.1.2 of the HTTP/1.1 protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) the GET request is idempotent i.e.

> the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request

This is the assumption that browsers use to claim that since a request to X causes a redirect to the same X then this is an infinite redirect and should be stopped.